# Terraform modules and providers

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a module that defines a provider as follows

```
provider "aws" {
    region                  = "${var.region}"
    shared_credentials_file = "${module.global_variables.shared_credentials_file}"
    profile                 = "${var.profile}"
}
```

and an EC instance as follows

```
resource "aws_instance" "node" {
    ami = "${lookup(var.ami, var.region)}"
    key_name   = "ib-us-east-2-production"
    instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
    count = "${var.count}"
    security_groups = "${var.security_groups}"
    tags {
        Name = "${var.name}"
    }
    root_block_device {
        volume_size = 100
    }
```

In the terraform script that calls this module, I would now like to create an ELB and attach it point it to the instance with something along the lines of

```
resource "aws_elb" "node_elb" {
    name               = "${var.name}-elb"
    .........
```

However terraform keeps prompting me for the aws region that is already defined in the module. The only way around this is to copy the provider block into the file calling the module. Is there a cleaner way to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The only way around this is to copy the provider block into the file calling the module.

The provider block should actually be in your file calling the module and you can remove it from your module.

From the docs:

> For convenience in simple configurations, a child module automatically inherits default (un-aliased) provider configurations from its parent. This means that explicit provider blocks appear only in the root module, and downstream modules can simply declare resources for that provider and have them automatically associated with the root provider configurations.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html#implicit-provider-inheritance